# How to get one record with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to develop a web api using `flask` and `sqlite`. For communication with db I'm using `sqlalchemy`.

In the code that I post below I have create a GET method to retrieve all data into a specific table into db:

```
from flask import Flask, g, Response, request, jsonify, abort
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask.ext.restless import APIManager
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from json import dumps
import sqlite3
import json


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///climb.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class falesie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'falesie'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    regione = db.Column(db.String(20))
    citta = db.Column(db.String(20))
    n_settori = db.Column(db.Integer)
    lat = db.Column(db.Float)
    lon = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __init__(self, regione, citta, n_settori, lat, lon):
      self.regione = regione
      self.citta = citta
      self.n_settori= n_settori
      self.lat = lat
      self.lon = lon

@app.route('/dev', methods = ['GET'])
def get_falesie():
    Falesie = falesie.query.all()
    formatted_falesie = []
    for f in Falesie:
        formatted_falesie.append({
        'id': f.id,
        'regione': f.regione,
        'citta': f.citta,
        'n_settori': f.n_settori,
        'lat': f.lat,
        'lon': f.lon})
    return json.dumps({'Falesie': formatted_falesie}), 200, {'Content-  Type': 'application/json'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I would like to create a `GET` method to retrieve a specific record with a specific value, as in this example:

```
@app.route('dev/<string:name>')
def get_data(name):
```

I don't know how to retrieve a single record. Any help please?

Comment: Which field do you want to use when querying `falesie`? It doesn't have a field `name`.

Comment: the field name is an example, the field is citta.

Answer (score 20):

This should help with getting a single result of `falesie`:

```
try:
    user = session.query(falesie).filter(name=name).one()  # filter on name
except MultipleResultsFound, e:
    print e
    # Deal with it
except NoResultFound, e:
    print e
    # Deal with that as well
```

Where [`session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#creating-a-session) is obtained as following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# an Engine, which the Session will use for connection resources
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///climb.db')

# create a configured "Session" class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# create a Session
session = Session()
```

See [`SQLAlchemy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/index.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: This should be `filter_by`, right? Maybe the API has changed since 2016?

Answer (score 15):

If you read [the tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying), you'll see that you can filter your query. Something like this should be what you want:

```
falesie.query().filter_by(id=name).first()
```

Comment: Remember query is not callable, use `falesie.query.filter_by(id=name).first()
`

Answer (score 4):

Question is very old but one more technique can help to others having problem.

```
def load_user(id):
    falesie.query.get(int(id))
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get

Answer (score 0):

For those now here looking for a way with SQLAlchemy 2.0--you can use
[this method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get_one) (`get_one()`):

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound

# create your session

try:
    obj = session.get_one(YourDbModel, pk_id)
except NoResultFound:
    # handle
```